# How to append string after file extension via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

Checking the integrity of zip archives recursively how can i rename bad files in a folder by appending a string after the file extension via a batch file under Windows?
I tried this script and it gives me no errors but doesn't rename bad files either.

```
FOR /R \backup %%A IN (*.zip) DO (
   7z t "%%A" | FIND "Everything is Ok" || ((REN "%%A" "%%A.bad") & (ECHO.%%A BAD >> error.log))
)
```

I have experience in PHP scripting and understand this code block in general (the meaning of the pipe and the logical OR operator). However, i have absolutely no experience in **Batch**-scripting and adopted the script from [this source](http://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/25bb18fb/). From what i understand the check receives either an "OK" or adds an entry to the log file and renames the file. The log entry is added, however the renaming is not applied. I don't understand why. Can you tell me what is going wrong and how it would have to look to work as intended?

Comment: Meaning of `commandA || commandB` using two vertical lines: run `commandA` and **if it fails** then run `commandB`. _If fails_, i.e. ends with non-zero return code, see also `errorlevel`. But your `commandA` never _fails_, as it displays a message for _right_ `.zip` files. So you should reformulate your condition.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a proper example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this batch code for your task.

```
@echo off
rem Test all ZIP files recursive from directory backup in root of
rem current drive and append .bad to those ZIP files not validate.
rem The names of those files are additionally written into an
rem error.log text file in current working directory.

for /R "\backup" %%A in (*.zip) do (
   7z.exe t "%%A">nul
   if errorlevel 1 (
      ren "%%A" "%%~nxA.bad"
      echo %%A BAD>>error.log
   )
)
```

In help of 7-zip there is a page about **Exit Codes**. As it can be read on this help page any value greater 0 means something was wrong.

Therefore `if errorlevel 1` can be used to check if the test on the ZIP file was positive (exit code is 0) or failed (value is greater or equal 1).

Look on help output in a command prompt window after entering `if /?` or `help if` for details about **errorlevel**. `if errorlevel 1` means: if exit code of previous command was greater or equal 1 then ...

Further command **ren** requires just new file name without path as second parameter as otherwise it does not rename the file specified with or without path as first parameter. This is the reason why `%%~nxA` must be used as second parameter for command **ren** to reference just name and extension of the file to rename. Help of command **for** output after entering `for /?` or `help for` contains a list of those modifier letters for a file name.

Comment: Can you tell me whether and how in conjuction with this script i can debug the currently processed path? I tried to echo it out directly above the line with 7z.exe like `ECHO %%A` and `ECHO "%%A"`. However i don't get the expected result. It simply echos out the term `%%A`. I'd like to extend the script and check whether a file exists in the currently processed directory. And if not, it should be extracted from the currently processed zip file. Let me know whether i should ask a new question for this.

Comment: `echo %%A` above line with `7z.exe` outputs the processed file with full path. `echo %%~dpA` would output just drive letter and path of the processed file. It would be better to ask a new question if you want to use this code with a modification and your modification does not work. Hint: Environment variables (not the loop variables) are expanded already before processing the loop except delayed expansion is used inside the loop. Enter `set /?` in a command prompt window and read from first to last help page to get explained delayed environment variable expansion.